# How would you go about writing $1/3=\sum\limits_{n=-k}^{\infty}a_n 2^{n}$ where $a_n=0,1$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I want to show that every $p$-adic number can be written as $\sum\limits_{n=-k}^{\infty}a_n p^{n}$ where $a_n=0,1,...,p-1$. But I got stuck with the example I came up with. By  *write* I am asking how to figure out the coefficients $a_n$.

Comment: I have to ask: what is $k$?

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^0 a_n2^n$?

Comment: @TedShifrin why? $1/3$ is a $2$-adic integer, in particular only the positive powers will count and moreover, the negative powers would have to terminate at a finite step, so there is no such representation.

Comment: @TedShifrin I want to abuse the property that there are least small intergers  $k$ such that $x=\sum\limits_{n=-k}^{\infty}a_np^{n}$ and $y=\sum\limits_{n=-k}^{\infty}b_np^{n}$ such that $val(x-y)=p^{k}$ where  $a_n,b_n=0,1,...,p-1$ and $val$ is the function such that $val(z)=p^{-m}$ when $z=p^{m}\frac{a}{b}$ and $p,a$ and $b$ are all relatively prime. Using this property it is easier to see the completion of $Q$ under the metric $d_p(x,y)=val(x-y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $3=2+1$, then with $3^{-1}=\sum a_n2^n$ we have

> $$1=3\cdot\sum_{n}a_n2^n = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+a_{n-1})2^n$$

So $a_0=1$ which implies $a_1=1$ since otherwise we have a $2^1$ not cancelable by anything. This implies $a_2+a_1+1$ has to be even in order to raise the next power i.e. it must be equal to $2$ as well--there are three summands, and one of them is $1$ so you cannot reach $0$ or $4$--and since $a_1=1$ we get $a_2=0$, and again we see $a_3+a_2+1=2$ so that $a_3=1$ and inductively we see $a_n+a_{n-1}+1=2$ each time (since $0$ or $4$ are impossible) and we conclude all the odd coefficients are $1$ and all the even ones are $0$ hence

> $$3^{-1} = 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{2n+1}$$

Comment: $1=1+(1+1)2+(0+1)2^2+(1+0)2^{3}+(0+1)2^{4}+...$?(p-adically)

Comment: @user160110 write it as

$$1= (1+2)\cdot \left(1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{2n+1}\right) = 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{2n+1} + 2 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{2n+2}=1+2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n$$

it's easier to see that way.

Answer (score 1):

Using what I’m hoping will be standard binary expansion of a $2$-adic number, the reciprocal of $1/3$ is $\dots10101011;\,$, meaning $1+2+8+32+128+\cdots$.

Check the geometric-series part of this, namely $2+8+32+\cdots$, evaluating as $2/(1-4)=-2/3$ using the formula for geometric series. Add $1$ and get $1/3$.

You can get to this result by doing long division of $11;$ into $1;\,$— unfortunately, this is hard to describe in print but easy at a blackboard. It proceeds right to left, unlike regular long division, which goes left to right.

Answer (score 1):

We know from the sum to infinity of a geometric progression that

$$1=\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 18+\frac 1{16}\cdots=(0.111111\cdots )_2$$

Here we want to find $x_2=1_{10}\div 3_{10}=1_2\div 11_2$ such that $$\begin{align}
x_2\cdot11_2&=1_2\\
&=(0.111111\cdots )_2\\
\Rightarrow x_2&=(0.0101010101\cdots)_2\\
&=\frac 1{2^2}+\frac 1{2^4}+\frac 1{2^6}+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^ \infty 2^{-2r}
\end{align}$$

Comment: You have given the binary expansion of the *real* number $1/3$, using (positive) powers of $1/2$.  OP has asked for the expansion of $1/3$ as a $2$-adic number, in (positive) powers of $2$.